# Results Tab of my Webform error: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: webforms

Clicking on the results tab: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Log message shows this error:
TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string in _*TwigTemplate*....

Will highly appreciate any pointers how to recover my results tag

Comment: Post the YAML of the form for an answer. It’s likely you upgraded to PHP 8 and have some custom Twig that is not handling data types properly. This has been asked many times. You should post the smallest form that shows this error.